# Using vs Utilizing

Tags: synonyms

My question is, which of the below sentences is more correct?

> - 1) Precise Mapping ***Using*** Unmanned Aerial Vehicle (UAV) data.
> - 2) Precise Mapping ***Utilizing*** Unmanned Aerial Vehicle (UAV) data.

And,

> - 1) Modern mapping ***utilizing*** laser scanners.
> - 2) Modern mapping ***using*** laser scanners.

I know both are correct, but as it would be a Thesis title, so in my opinion here as I am using a Sensor or Machine, therefore ***utilizing*** looks more correct, but I need to be sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

*Using*.

If there is a difference it is presumably that *use* means *make use of* while *utilize* means *make useful*, i.e. turn something into a tool.

But the overlap in the Venn diagram you could draw for those meanings would be large. Many things become useful the moment you use them.

That, combined with popular hypercorrection of *use* to *utilize* (i.e. using the longer word for a perceived improvement over the shorter one), has made their current usage nearly indistinguishable.

But it's actually usually a safe bet that *use* will work, and it's much easier to say and write even if it's only a threepenny word.

Comment: I would say UTILIZE is better than USING. Because, 'utilize' is more appropriate vocabulary in the context of what you are trying to say( the context here is formal+machine-related).

Comment: @John There is nothing formal or machine-related in *utilize* that isn't in *use* as well.

Comment: i'm just saying its a better vocabulary in those examples given.

Comment: That's the opposite conclusion from mine and sees the difference between the two words differently from how I do, so a separate answer would make more sense than a clarifying comment.